# Github Repository File access

Tags: github

I am an amateur coder and I want to go through this repository https://github.com/Illedan/Bit-Runner-2048 to understand some physics and coding concepts. I have found that there is some files, the boss.cs and boss.cpp files which I cannot find. 
https://github.com/Illedan/Bit-Runner-2048/search?q=boss&unscoped_q=boss does not yeild any results. I would like to read and understand it, so if possible, can you tell me how to open that file?

Comment: How do you know that the `boss.cs` and `boss.cpp` are really present in the same repo?

Comment: Is it possible for it to be accessed from another repository?

Comment: If so, how do I find this repository?

Comment: Well, how can I answer about the repository and files which only you know about? Where did you get to know about the existence of those files and what did that point to?

Comment: Also, there are other repositories that are similar which I have gone through, in all of those cases, the boss file was in the config folder. And if you open the search link, you will see this line of code in another file  file="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/config/Boss.cs"> so it has to be in a config folder

Comment: The Boss.cs and Boss.cpp are added to the [gitignore](https://github.com/Illedan/Bit-Runner-2048/blob/master/.gitignore#L26-L27) and hence are not supposed to be part of the GitHub repository. And that's why you arent able to find them in the repo.

Comment: In that case, any idea where I can find these files?